# How can I run this curl command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, curl

```
curl --request PROPFIND --url "http://carddav.mail.aol.com/home/testuser@aol.com/Contacts/" --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --header "Depth: 1" --data '<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:"><A:prop><A:getetag /><D:address-data xmlns:D="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"/></A:prop></A:propfind>' --header "Authorization: Bearer fjskdlfjds"
```

Is there a particular method in Net::HTTP that allows the propfind command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Net::HTTP::Propfind
```

Here is an example:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://example.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Propfind.new(uri.request_uri)

# Set your body (data)
request.body = "Here's the body."

# Set your headers: one header per line.
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

response = http.request(request)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it would be that simple.